# Autoclick on a href link without scrolling with pure JS

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem there. I have accordion tabs with custom a tags. You can see the code below. I made a JS code to autoclick on different tab when the page is loaded. It works nice but it's scrolling down to the tab. I am not good in JS so  I just come here to get help or advice. For me it will be better to not use "something a" but "#discussion" because there can be more tabs and I like to choose  which tab will be autoclicked by the hash link not with "nth-child".

I can't use ID's on taband can't use jQuery (don't have permissions, just can use JS and adding code to body/head/footer)

Thank you! :-)

```
<div id="tabs-div" class="some-classes">
   <ul id="tabs" class="some-classes">
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
         <a href="#description" title="Description" class="tiny button">Description</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
         <a href="#discussion" title="Discussion" class="tiny button">Discussion</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
<div>

<script>
$link = $('#tabs li:last-child a');
$link[0].click()
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use jQuery...yet your script block has ...jQuery?: `$link = $('#tabs li:last-child a');
location.href = $link.attr('href');` How does this work well when you cannot use jQuery?

Comment: @zer00ne That's strange. I want use <code>$('a[href="#discussionTab"]').trigger('click');</code> but it's not work but no error will show up.

Comment: Are the `<code>` tags a typo or are you expecting `<code>$('a[href="#discussionTab"]').trigger('click');</code>` to actually work as script? `<code>` renders script as plain text. If you want to run that bit successfully you need to do two things: 1. replace the `<code>` tags with `<script>` tags. 2. load jQuery. Are you aware that every line of JavaScript you have is jQuery to which you have no permission to use?

Comment: @zer00ne No, I just want to edit this post and show code, sorry. If I the function above use on my site with <script>function</script> the script not work. The only script which work is the main in my post.

Comment: Ok, I'll repeat once more, please read very carefully: Why are you using jQuery when you said that you have no permission to use jQuery?

Comment: @zer00ne Maybe because I think it's not jQuery code :-) Because I have tried trigger funkction but it's not work too.

Comment: It won't work because it's jQuery to which your site supposedly rejects. Please read carefully: **All of the code you have posted is jQuery**

Comment: Just because someone uses a function named `$()` doesnt mean its automagically jQuery. I always name my dom selection functions `$()` and I never use jQuery.

Comment: @zer00ne So I am a little bit smarter now. Can you advice me how to make it not jumping to section? Or improve my code?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Your `$` is `querySelector()/querySelectorAll()`  so what? OP's code is jQuery as the original was `$link.attr('href')` and `attr()` is deprecated in plain JavaScript

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt `$('a[href="#discussionTab"]').trigger('click');` is jQuery  as well.

Comment: @zer00ne But this code doesn't work on my site :-/

Comment: @PatrikŠtolba the tabs that your links scroll to like for example: `<a href='#discussion'...>` will open a accordion and scroll to a tab: `<div id='discussion'>` correct?

Comment: @zer00ne Yeah, if I open the page where tab with that link is, it automatically scroll down to the open tab. But I don't to make it scroll down ( and for me it will be better if the script found the tab because of a href="#discussion" not because of "last-child".

Comment: @zer00ne Well, trigger() is a jQuery function, yes. But there is no trigger() function in the OP right NOW. I haven´t even seen that he edited his post, because only the post as it is right now matters to me, so chill.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Yeah,it was my fault I just insert current code I am using. The older one was a mistake.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt review the comments thoroughly. Your argument was that OP is not necessarily using jQuery, I said OP was purely by what was posted in questions and comments. I don't see what you are trying to say because you based your comments upon what I have commented upon but you are saying that whatever is commented doesn't matter only what is currently posted?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt so what you suggest I do...erase all comments not current to the what's currently posted? And maybe disregard whatever was commented in the past?

Comment: @PatrikŠtolba can you post some of the accordion and also the HTML of the location that your link scrolls to?

Comment: @zer00ne Well,just visit https://247202.myshoptet.com/hodinky/suunto-core-alu-black/